# I can't get wordpress custom footer to work on about us page

Tags: wordpress

So I was able to get a custom footer to show for front-page.php using the following code:

````
    <?php 
    if(is_page(2436)) {
     get_footer('two');
    }
    else {
     get_footer();
    }
     wp_footer();
    ?>
    ``` 
If I try to use this code changing the page ID to the about us page and adding it to page.php it changes my footer but it doesn't show me the footer I created.
````

```
<?php 
if(is_page('2286')) {
 get_footer('two');
}
else {
 get_footer();
}
 wp_footer();?>
```

Comment: You put the second one in quotes. Try it without the quotes.

Comment: I had it as a slug before but it still doesn't work even without quotes. I just created a page template and just figured out that that will work for what I am trying to do, just going to abandon the custom footer on this.

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on in wp-config? Any particular errors for that scenario?

Comment: No I didn't have it on because was working on the site live, but will keep that in mind for for the future.